# "Blog App By Django " error: comment_list can't by displayed currectly

Tags: python, django

There is a blog app by Django 1.9. But when I want to show a comment_list in article.html, there has some trouble. Comment_list can't be displayed in Article Page.

[Article Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTBYZ.png)

view.py is below:

```
       46 def article(request):                                                            
       47     try:                                                                         
       48         id = request.GET.get('id', None)                                         
       49         try:                                                                     
       50             article = Article.objects.get(pk=id)                                 
       51             # 评论表单                                                           
       52             comment_form = CommentForm({'author': request.user.username,         
       53                                         'email': request.user.email,             
       54                                         'url': request.user.url,                 
    CC 55                                          'article': id}                          
       56                                        if request.user.is_authenticated()        
       57                                        else {'article': id})                     
       58                                                                                  
       59             comments = Comment.objects.filter(article=article).order_by('id')    
       60             comment_list = []                                                    
       61             for comment in comments:                                             
       62                 for item in comment_list:                                        
       63                     if not hasattr(item, 'children_comment'):                    
       64                         setattr(item, 'children_comment', [])                    
       65                     if comment.pid == item:                                      
       66                         item.children_comment.append(comment)                    
       67                         break                                                    
       68                 if commend.pid is None:                                               
       69                     comment_list.append(comment)                                 
       70         except Article.DoesNotExist:                                             
       71             return render(request, 'failure.html', {'reason': '没有对应的文章'}) 
       72     except Exception as e:                                                       
       73         print e                                                                  
       74         logger.error(e)                                                          
       75     return render(request, 'article.html', locals())                             
       76
```

html is here:

```
 <ol class="commentlist">
          {% for comment in comment_list %}
          <li id="comment-59418">
                <div class="top"><a href='{{ comment.url }}' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>{{ comment.username }}</a><span class="time"> @ <a href="#comment-59418" title="">{{ comment.date_publish | date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}</a></span></div>
                <div><img alt='' src='{% static 'images/default.jpg' %}' class='avatar avatar-32 photo' height='32' width='32' /></div>

                <div class="body">
                                <p>{{ comment.content | safe }}</p>
                </div>
          </li>
          {% for children_comment in comment.children_comment %}
          <li id="comment-59542">
                <div class="reply">
                  <div class="top"><a href="{{ children_comment.url }}" rel="external nofollow" class="url">{{ children_comment.username }}</a><span class="time"> @ <a href="#comment-59543" title="">{{ children_comment.date_publish | date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}</a></span></div>
                  <div><img alt="" src="{% static 'images/default.jpg' %}" class="avatar avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32"></div>

                  <div class="body">
                                        {{ children_comment.content }}                  </div>
                </div>
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      </ol>
```

Comment: Can you show us `Comment` model?

Comment: `content = models.TextField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date_publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, blank=True, null=True)
    pid = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)·`

Comment: Please add any relevant code - like the one in the comment above - as part of the question's text. It is hard to comprehend like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

`pid = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children_comments', blank=True, null=True)`

Then, you don't need comment_list at all:

```
def article(request):                                                            
    try:                                                                         
        id = request.GET.get('id', None)                                         
        try:                                                                     
            article = Article.objects.get(pk=id)                                 
            # 评论表单                                                           
            comment_form = CommentForm({
                'author': request.user.username,
                'email': request.user.email,             
                'url': request.user.url,                 
                'article': id}
                if request.user.is_authenticated() else {
                'article': id
            })                     

            comments = Comment.objects.filter(article=article).order_by('id')                                 
        except Article.DoesNotExist:                                             
            return render(request, 'failure.html', {'reason': '没有对应的文章'}) 
    except Exception as e:                                                       
        print e                                                                  
        logger.error(e)                                                          
    return render(request, 'article.html', locals())
```

Just use `comment.children_comments.all` in template, it should work

```
<ol class="commentlist">
{% for comment in comment_list %}
    <li id="comment-59418">
        <div class="top">
            <a href='{{ comment.url }}' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>{{ comment.username }}</a>
            <span class="time"> @ <a href="#comment-59418" title="">{{ comment.date_publish | date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}</a></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img alt='' src='{% static 'images/default.jpg' %}' class='avatar avatar-32 photo' height='32' width='32' />
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <p>{{ comment.content | safe }}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    {% for children_comment in comment.children_comments.all %}
    <li id="comment-59542">
        <div class="reply">
            <div class="top">
                <a href="{{ children_comment.url }}" rel="external nofollow" class="url">{{ children_comment.username }}</a>
                <span class="time"> @ <a href="#comment-59543" title="">{{ children_comment.date_publish | date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}</a></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img alt="" src="{% static 'images/default.jpg' %}" class="avatar avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32">
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                {{ children_comment.content | safe }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

**Note:** you forgot `safe` template tag. And you have the same html ids for all of `<li>`.